# Every EXE wants to open in Blender after setting that default for .blend files

Tags: windows

Windows 10 didn't associate my .blend files with the Blender software. So I went to one of these file's properties, and I selected blender.exe as the program to be opened in.

I immediately knew I screwed up. Almost every icon changed to Blender's icon, and when I click on, let's say Google Chrome, it launches in Blender, or at least it tries to, but then it closes immediately. Same with everything else, such as Steam or foobar2000, really anything.

I found the command prompt solution, but that is also affected by this issue (a.k.a. it doesn't open properly either). Same with restoring a previous point. The only solution so fat I could find that could work is the regedit one. I found *this* bit of "code":

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.exe\UserChoice]

Which I made into a .txt on my phone, got it over to my pc, then saved it as a .reg to my desktop via Notepad (which still works). So now I have this .reg file on my desktop, but I don't "dare" merging it yet because I'm not sure if it wouldn't cause any more harm.

I don't even understand how it happened, because I don't think I did anything wrong. I actually remember having this exact problem like 10 years ago when everything opened in Notepad, through a similar chain of events. I don't know what to do.

Comment: That registry file won't hurt your computer.  If you are still having problems after running it and rebooting, please let us know.  I too do not know how this happened.  The explorer "normally" won't allow you to re-associate exe files (for obvious reasons).

Comment: It didn't do anything sadly :/ I did the "open in" thing in Total Commander btw

Comment: Either way, run the script.  If it doesn't work, they messed with another part of the registry (the old way).. I can tell you how to fix that too if the above .REG file doesn't work.